# Download file using fastapi

Tags: python, python-3.x

I see the functions for [uploading in an API](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/request-files/), but I don't see how to download. Am I missing something? I want to create an API for a file download site. Is there a different API I should be using?

```
from typing import List
from fastapi import FastAPI, Query

app = FastAPI()
PATH "some/path"

@app.get("/shows/")
    def get_items(q: List[str] = Query(None)):
        '''
        Pass path to function.
        Returns folders and files.
        '''
    
        results = {}
    
        query_items = {"q": q}
        entry = PATH + "/".join(query_items["q"]) + "/"

        dirs = os.listdir(entry)
        results["folders"] = [val for val in dirs if os.path.isdir(entry+val)]
        results["files"] = [val for val in dirs if os.path.isfile(entry+val)]
        results["path_vars"] = query_items["q"]
    
        return results
```

Here is the sample bit of code for python to fetch files and dirs for a path, you can return the path as a list with a new entry in a loop to go deeper into a file tree. Passing a file name should trigger a download function, but I cant seem to get a download func going.

Comment: https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/response-model/#add-an-output-model

Comment: I dont see how to download file here.. sorry , can you help me out

Comment: What kind of file do you want to get when you call `/shows/` JSON? You basically want a file with a bunch of folder and files names?

Comment: Related answers can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72053557/17865804), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73240097/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73843234/17865804), as well as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73580096/17865804), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73414443/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71193588/17865804).

Answer (score 46, accepted):

This worked For me

```
from starlette.responses import FileResponse

return FileResponse(file_location, media_type='application/octet-stream',filename=file_name)
```

This will download the file with filename

Comment: looks like `fastapi` re-exports `FileResponse` as of the time of my writing this (2021-02): https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/custom-response/?h=content+dispo#fileresponse

Answer (score 33):

Since we're talking about FastAPI, the proper way to return a file response is covered in [their documentation](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/custom-response/?h=fileresponse#fileresponse), code snippet below:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.responses import FileResponse

file_path = "large-video-file.mp4"
app = FastAPI()

@app.get("/")
def main():
    return FileResponse(path=file_path, filename=file_path, media_type='text/mp4')
```

Answer (score 9):

FastAPI uses Starlette's FileResponse class so there are two ways to import `FileResponse` on your API code. But of course importing from FastAPI would be a better choice. You can follow the approach below to enable your API endpoints support file download.

Do not forget to add `aiofiles` to your dependency list. A basic `requirements.txt` file should look like (versions of modules might change in time, version 0.63.0 of fastapi strictly use starlette 0.13.6)

```
uvicorn==0.13.4
fastapi==0.63.0
starlette==0.13.6
aiofiles==0.6.0
```

And the API code

```
import os

from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.responses import FileResponse


app = FastAPI()


@app.get("/")
async def main():
    file_name = "FILE NAME"
    # DEPENDS ON WHERE YOUR FILE LOCATES
    file_path = os.getcwd() + "/" + file_name
    return FileResponse(path=file_path, media_type='application/octet-stream', filename=file_name)
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out,

```
from starlette.responses import FileResponse
@app.get("/shows/")
    def get_items(q: List[str] = Query(None)):
    '''
    Pass path to function.
    Returns folders and files.
    '''

    results = {}

    query_items = {"q": q}
    if query_items["q"]:
        entry = PATH + "/".join(query_items["q"])
    else:
        entry = PATH

    if os.path.isfile(entry):
        return download(entry)

    dirs = os.listdir(entry + "/")
    results["folders"] = [
        val for val in dirs if os.path.isdir(entry + "/"+val)]
    results["files"] = [val for val in dirs if os.path.isfile(entry + "/"+val)]
    results["path_vars"] = query_items["q"]

    return results

def download(file_path):
    """
    Download file for given path.
    """
    if os.path.isfile(file_path):
        return FileResponse(file_path)
        # return FileResponse(path=file_path)
    return None
```

I added this part

```
from starlette.responses import FileResponse
if os.path.isfile(entry):
    return download(entry)
```

Allows you to host static file. But for some reason all files download as "download" .extension. If you know how to ensure original file name, let me know.

Comment: What is inside the `download` function?

Comment: FileResponse receives more parameters:
FileResponse(path=file_path, media_type=media_type, filename=file_name)

Answer (score 0):

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.responses import FileResponse
import uvicorn
import os

app = FastAPI()

@app.get("/download-file")
def download_file(file_name: str):
    folder_path = r"C:\Users\HP\Desktop\excel files"
    file_location = f'{folder_path}{os.sep}{file_name}.xlsx'#os.sep is used to seperate with a \
    return FileResponse(file_location, media_type='application/octet-stream', filename=file_name)


uvicorn.run(app, port=9105)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

@scipioafricanus, I used the below code, and it also saves the filename during the download. I used a streamingResponse to handle large files as well. Please keep in mind that there might be limitations on large files (file_size >10mb) under starlette configuration and hence need to be changed accordingly to handle large files (file_size >10mb).

> 

```
try:
    # Create the folder path based on project_id and results_set_name
    result_set_path = get_result_set_path(project_id, results_set_name)

    # Check if the project/result_set_name folder exists
    if not os.path.exists(result_set_path):
        raise HTTPException(status_code=404, detail=f"{project_id}/{results_set_name} Folder not found")

    # Get the list of files in the folder
    files = [f for f in os.listdir(result_set_path) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(result_set_path, f))]

    # Check if there are any files in the folder
    if not files:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=404, detail=f"No files found in the {result_set_path} path")

    # Get the path of the first file
    first_file_path = os.path.join(result_set_path, files[0])

    # Determine the media type based on the file extension
    mime_type, _ = mimetypes.guess_type(first_file_path)
    media_type = mime_type or "application/octet-stream"

    # Set Content-Disposition header with the correct filename and extension
    headers = {"Content-Disposition": f'inline; filename="{files[0]}"'}

    # Return the file as a response
    # return FileResponse(first_file_path, media_type=media_type, filename=os.path.basename(first_file_path), headers=headers)

    # Return the file as a streaming response
    return StreamingResponse(
        open(first_file_path, "rb"),
        media_type=media_type,  # Set appropriate media type based on the file type
        headers=headers,  # Set Content-Disposition header with the correct filename and extension
    )

except Exception as e:
    raise HTTPException(status_code=500, detail=f"Failed to download Original Results file: {str(e)}")
```