# How do I download a file from FastAPI backend using JavaScript Fetch API in the frontend?

Tags: javascript, python, html, fetch-api, fastapi

This is my FastAPI(python) code, which returns a `.ics` file:

```
@app.get("/latLong/")
async def read_item(lat: float,long:float):
    mainFunc(lat,long)
    return FileResponse("/tmp/myics.ics")
```

This is my frontend code in Javascript using Fetch API:

```js
<script>
  async function apiCall(long,lat) {
    let myObject = await fetch('myapi.com/lat/long');
    let myText = await myObject.text();
  }
</script>
```

So from my visor (my api logs), it successfully calls the API. But from the front end, I am trying to get it to return the file.

The end result I would like to achieve is when the user clicks a button, the browser grabs the location, then sends the location to the API, and the API returns a file that the user can download.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Server side

First, you need to adjust your endpoint on server side to accept [`path`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/path-params/) parameters, as in the way that is currently defined, `lat` and `long` are expected to be [`query`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/query-params/) parameters instead; however, in the JavaScript code you provided, it seems that you are trying to send those coordinates as `path` parameters. Thus, your endpoint should look like this:

```py
@app.get("/{lat}/{long}/")
async def read_item(lat: float, long: float):
    pass
```

Next, set the `filename` in [`FileResponse`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/custom-response/#fileresponse), so that it can be included in the [`Content-Disposition`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition) response header, which can later be retrieved on client side:

```py
return FileResponse("/tmp/myics.ics", filename="myics.ics")
```

If you are doing a [cross-origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) request (see [FastAPI CORS](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/cors/) as well), make sure to set the [`Access-Control-Expose-Headers`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#access-control-expose-headers) response header on server side, indicating that the `Content-Disposition` header should be made available to JS scripts running in the browser; otherwise, the `filename` won't be accessible on client side. Example:

```py
headers = {'Access-Control-Expose-Headers': 'Content-Disposition'}
return FileResponse("/tmp/myics.ics", filename="myics.ics", headers=headers)
```

All together (more details and examples can be found at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73240097/17865804) as well):

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.responses import FileResponse


app = FastAPI()


@app.get("/{lat}/{long}/")
async def read_item(lat: float, long: float):
    headers = {'Access-Control-Expose-Headers': 'Content-Disposition'}
    return FileResponse("/tmp/myics.ics", filename="myics.ics", headers=headers)
```

### Client side

On client side, you could use a similar approach to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73240097/17865804) or [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73414443/17865804). The below example also takes into account scenarios where the `filename` includes unicode characters (i.e., `-, !, (, )`, etc.) and hence, comes (utf-8 encoded) in the form of, for instance, `filename*=utf-8''Na%C3%AFve%20file.txt` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/93551/how-to-encode-the-filename-parameter-of-content-disposition-header-in-http) for more details). In such cases, the [`decodeURIComponent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent) function is used to decode the `filename`. Working example below:

```js
const url ='http://127.0.0.1:8000/41.64007/-47.285156'
fetch(url)
    .then(res => {
        const disposition = res.headers.get('Content-Disposition');
        filename = disposition.split(/;(.+)/)[1].split(/=(.+)/)[1];
        if (filename.toLowerCase().startsWith("utf-8''"))
            filename = decodeURIComponent(filename.replace("utf-8''", ''));
        else
            filename = filename.replace(/['"]/g, '');
        return res.blob();
    })
    .then(blob => {
        var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        var a = document.createElement('a');
        a.href = url;
        a.download = filename;
        document.body.appendChild(a); // append the element to the dom
        a.click();
        a.remove(); // afterwards, remove the element  
    });
```