# how to return word doc/file in fastapi?

Tags: python, ms-word, fastapi

Im trying to build an endpoint with GET requests, that only return a word document in my local . but it's working , it keep give me "Internal Server Error".
sorry I'm new to fastapi i don't know how to debug the error.

here is what I tried :

```
@app.get("/file/uploadndownload")
def upload_n_downloadfile():

    word_document_path = "C:\\Users\\Yaz\\Desktop\\"
    SAVE_FILE_PATH = os.path.join(word_document_path, "documentation")
    # Return the Word document as a response
    return FileResponse(
        path=SAVE_FILE_PATH,
        filename="documentation",
        media_type="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document")
```

Comment: In addition to the link provided above, related answers could be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71193588/17865804), as well as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73241648/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73240097/17865804)