# How to download a file using ReactJS with Axios in the frontend and FastAPI in the backend?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, axios, fastapi

I am trying to create a `docx` file and send it to the frontend client app, so that it can be downloaded to the user's local machine. I am using FastAPI for the backend. I am using `python-docx` library also to create the `Document`.

The code below is used to create a `docx` file and save it to the server.

```
@app.post("/create_file")
async def create_file(data: Item):
    document = Document()
    document.add_heading("file generated", level=1)
    document.add_paragraph("test")
    document.save('generated_file.docx')
    return {"status":"Done!"}
```

The below code is then used to send the created `docx` file as a `FileResponse` to the client.

```
@app.get("/generated_file")
async def download_generated_file():
    file_path = "generated_file.docx"
    return FileResponse(file_path, media_type='application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document', filename=file_path)
```

On Client side (I am using ReactJS):

```js
createFile = async () => {
   const data = {
      start: this.state.start,
      end: this.state.end,
      text: this.state.text,
   };
   await axios.post("http://localhost:8000/create_file", data).then(() => {
      console.log("processing completed!");
   });
};

downloadFile = async () => {
   await axios.get("http://localhost:8000/generated_file").then((res) => {
      const url = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([res.data]));
      const link = document.createElement("a");
      link.href = url;
      link.setAttribute("download", "generated.txt");
      link.click();
   });
};
```

The `generated.docx` file gets downloaded when `downloadFile` function is called. However, the `docx` file is always **corrupted** and doesn't open. I tried using txt file and it works fine. I need to use **docx** file, so what can I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the Axios `GET` request, you have to make sure the `responseType` parameter is set to `blob`. Once you get the `response` from the API, you will need to pass the [`Blob`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob) object (i.e., `response.data`) to the [`URL.createObjectURL()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL) function. Below is a fully working example on how to create and download a file (`Document`), using either Axios or Fetch API in the frontend. This answer utilises methods and code excerpts from [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71324775/17865804) and [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73240097/17865804) answer, as well as the answers [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71195901/17865804) and [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71193588/17865804). Plesase refer to the above answers for more details on the methods used below. For demo purposes, the below example uses `Jinja2Templates`, but, in a similar way, you can use the scripts below in your ReactJS app.

**app.py**

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request
from fastapi.templating import Jinja2Templates
from fastapi.responses import FileResponse
from docx import Document

app = FastAPI()
templates = Jinja2Templates(directory="templates")


@app.get('/')
def main(request: Request):
    return templates.TemplateResponse("index.html", {"request": request})
    
@app.post("/create")
def create_file():
    document = Document()
    document.add_heading("file generated", level=1)
    document.add_paragraph("test")
    document.save('generated_file.docx')
    return {"status":"Done!"}
    
@app.get("/download")
def download_generated_file():
    file_path = "generated_file.docx"
    return FileResponse(file_path, media_type='application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document', filename=file_path)
```

### Using Axios

tempaltes/**index.htnl**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Create and Download a Document</title>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.27.2/axios.min.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <input type="button" value="Create Document" onclick="createFile()">
      <div id="response"></div><br>
      <input type="button" value="Download Document " onclick="downloadFile()">
      <script>
         function createFile() {
            axios.post('/create', {
                  headers: {
                     'Accept': 'application/json',
                     'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                  }
               })
               .then(response => {
                  document.getElementById("response").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(response.data);
               })
               .catch(error => {
                  console.error(error);
               });
         }
         
         function downloadFile() {
            axios.get('/download', {
                  responseType: 'blob'
               })
               .then(response => {
                  const disposition = response.headers['content-disposition'];
                  filename = disposition.split(/;(.+)/)[1].split(/=(.+)/)[1];
                  if (filename.toLowerCase().startsWith("utf-8''"))
                     filename = decodeURIComponent(filename.replace("utf-8''", ''));
                  else
                     filename = filename.replace(/['"]/g, '');
                  return response.data;
               })
               .then(blob => {
                  var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                  var a = document.createElement('a');
                  a.href = url;
                  a.download = filename;
                  document.body.appendChild(a); // append the element to the dom
                  a.click();
                  a.remove(); // afterwards, remove the element  
               })
               .catch(error => {
                  console.error(error);
               });
         }
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

### Using Fetch API

tempaltes/**index.htnl**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Create and Download a Document</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <input type="button" value="Create Document" onclick="createFile()">
      <div id="response"></div><br>
      <input type="button" value="Download Document" onclick="downloadFile()">
      <script>
         function createFile() {
            fetch('/create', {
                  method: 'POST',
                  headers: {
                     'Accept': 'application/json',
                     'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                  }
               })
               .then(response => response.text())
               .then(data => {
                  document.getElementById("response").innerHTML = data;
               })
               .catch(error => {
                  console.error(error);
               });
         }
         
         function downloadFile() {
            fetch('/download')
               .then(response => {
                  const disposition = response.headers.get('Content-Disposition');
                  filename = disposition.split(/;(.+)/)[1].split(/=(.+)/)[1];
                  if (filename.toLowerCase().startsWith("utf-8''"))
                     filename = decodeURIComponent(filename.replace("utf-8''", ''));
                  else
                     filename = filename.replace(/['"]/g, '');
                  return response.blob();
               })
               .then(blob => {
                  var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                  var a = document.createElement('a');
                  a.href = url;
                  a.download = filename;
                  document.body.appendChild(a); // append the element to the dom
                  a.click();
                  a.remove(); // afterwards, remove the element
               })
               .catch(error => {
                  console.error(error);
               });
         }
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This implies that the full file is first loaded in memory and then save to disk, right ? Is there some way to avoid that ?

Comment: @leonbloy The example above is based on OP's needs, where the file has to be created and served by two different endpoints. Sure you can avoid that, by returning a `Response` directly. Please have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71639658/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73586180/17865804), as well as at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71643439/17865804), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71728386/17865804) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73580096/17865804) answer.